# AESManaged error after migrating to .Net 5

Tags: .net, aes, .net-5

I have a crypt service class which has the following code:

```
 public static string Encrypt(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return null;

        return Transform(texto, _cryptoService.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV));
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return texto;

        return Transform(texto, _cryptoService.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV));
    }

    private static string Transform(string text, ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            byte[] input = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);

            cryptoStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);

            if (input.Length > 0)
            {
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }

            return Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

In an existing .Net Framework WebAPI it works perfectly. However, I have to use the same algorithm in a new .Net 5 project and I'm getting the exception "the input data is not a complete block" on decrypt method.

Comment: Where specifically are you seeing the error?

Comment: This is probably due to `Encoding.Default` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0), which is defined differently in .NET Framework (system's active code page) and .NET Core (UTF8). In general, a ciphertext must not be encoded with a charset encoding such as UTF8, since this corrupts the data. If a ciphertext is to be converted to a string, then a [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) such as Base64 should be used.